# Transformer library not installed in anaconda

Tags: import

I am using Anaconda 3.10.9 version. At this time, with the code from transformers import BertForTokenClassification
I'm having trouble trying to import it.

error code: ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\mdc-int-80\anaconda3\lib\collections_*init*_.py)
Process finished with exit code 1

!pip install sentencepiece and
Tried !pip install transformers-3.3.0. I tried it in several places, including in the pycharm terminal and in the anaconda prompt.